# Do I have to open source our website if using an AGPL task queue?

Tags: agpl-3.0, website

We are running a web-based photo processing service, the architecture is as follows:

```
Web backend -(photo to process)-> [task queue] --> worker -(processed photo)-> Object storage
```

The task queue is only exposed to our web backend program. To be specific, we plan to use [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/license.html) which is (EDIT: **was**, as they changed it to LGPL in 2018) licensed under AGPL. Do we need to open source our program in this case? If so, which part of our code should be open-sourced?

Comment: Are you modifying dramatiq or just using it?  Either way it shouldn't infect the rest of your site.

Comment: @chicks We are just using the original distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Dramatiq is not covered by the AGPL but [by the LGPL](https://dramatiq.io/license.html):

> Project License
>
> Copyright (C) 2017,2018 CLEARTYPE SRL
>
> Dramatiq is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
>
> Dramatiq is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

You can **use** it without having your code license affected in any way.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the license on Dramatiq changed from AGPL to LGPL om 13 march 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Dramatiq appears to also provide a Commercial license.

See https://dramatiq.io/commercial.html

> #### Commercial Licensing
>
> Commercial licensing is available to companies or individuals that do not wish to publish their source code. Commercial licenses are invoiced anually and come with NET30 terms. Each license costs $2,000 per year.
>
> Companies that are just starting out may get a commercial license free for one year. Ask about this in the “Additional Notes” section when you fill out the form below and tell me about your use case.
>
> If you’re interested in purchasing a commercial license, fill out this form and I’ll get back to you within one business day.